# Nhibernate Generate wrong SQL for Oracle with locking

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, locking

yesterday I've been trying to make this code work inspite the fact it's just working fine with nhibernate and SQL server but when it come to oracle it generate wrong sql

```
UnitOfWork.Current.CreateCriteria<Bill>().Add(Restrictions.IsEmpty("ReqId"))
.SetMaxResults(BatchSize).SetLockMode(LockMode.Upgrade).List<Bill>();
```

the generated SQL will something like

```
Select * from 
(Select bill_0.id,bill_0.BillNo ...... from Bill bill_0 where bill_0.reqId is Not null )
where ROWNUM < 10 for UPDATE of bill_0.ID
```

so i wont run because the allies bill_o is defined inside the inner sql statement  so who got the solution ?

the correct sql would be something like this which i tried and worked on oracle db

```
Select bill_0.id,bill_0.BillNo ...... from Bill bill_0 
where bill_0.reqId is Not null and ROWNUM < 10 for UPDATE of bill_0.ID
```

Comment: Kindly, could you point out what the benefit of using locking here.
According to NH Docs "advanced users may sometimes wish to obtain exclusive pessimistic locks" So, how it's useful here. Also It would be better to add the expected SQL to be generated.

Comment: simply to prevent other threads from updating my record set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as you say, NHibernate is generating invalid Oracle SQL, I suggest you file a bug with the NHibernate people.  The SQL would work if the in-line view had been assigned an alias of "bill_0", or if the FOR UPDATE clause didn't use a table alias ("for UPDATE of ID").  Whether you can modify your NHibernate calls to make either of these happen I'm afraid I have no idea.

Comment: i guess so it's a bug i hope its fixed at Nhibernate 3